# Using jquery ui nested accordion with a list content pushed down in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

hello I have a jquery UI accordion with a nested list inside. When you mouse over the tab February 19 you get another accordion that appears inside the accordion. When you click November 2001. a list appears, but in IE7 every time you mouse over November 2001 tab the content gets pushed down. I have poured over this and have found posts of similar issues that haven't been answered any help appreciated. Please review my fiddle.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("ul.docsAccordion").accordion({
   collapsible: true,
   active: false,
   heightStyle: "content"
  }); //end jquery ui accordion
  
var x = $("div.masthead a:first").attr('href'); //check the link in page for query string french or english
var lang = x.slice(-2);

  if (lang==='fr'){ 
//replace english with french in datatable.min.js 
var sortdn = ": Trier les résultats par ordre croissant";
var sortup = ": Trier les résultats par ordre décroissant";
var locale = "fr";
}
 $('table#docListTable').dataTable({ // table#docListTable initialize multiple tables on one page
  "oLanguage": {
     "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": sortup,
        "sSortDescending": sortdn
  }
 },
"bFilter": false, //hide filter
"paging":   false, //shut off multiple paging this is not the case 
"bInfo": false //hide entry info at bottom of table
} );
});
```

```css
/*****************Nested Accordion************************/
input:focus { outline: none; }
a {
 color: #000000;
 outline: none !important;
}

ul{
margin-top:20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.singleColumn li h2{padding-left:20px;}
.docsAccordion {
  background-color: #fbf5db;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
 color: #000000;
}
ul.docsAccordion > li{
 border-bottom: thick solid #ffffff;
 text-align:left;
}

 /***turn off links inside the accordion h3 h2 and links***/
  ul.docsAccordion  > li a:link{
 text-decoration:none !important;
   color:#000000 !important;
}
  ul.docsAccordion > li a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
   color:#000000;
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
  ul.docsAccordion  > li a:visited{
 text-decoration:none !important;
   color:#000000 !important;
   
}
 ul.docsAccordion  > li h2 a:hover{
 text-decoration:none !important;
   color:#000000 !important;
}
 ul.docsAccordion  > li h2 a:visited{
 text-decoration:none !important;
   color:#000000 !important;
}

.dataTable a { /***turn on links inside the datatable***/
 text-decoration:underline !important;
 }
li.nestedElems{  /*list inside accordion*/
padding-left:5px !important;
margin-left:0px !important;
 border-bottom: none;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 text-align:left;
 border: 1px solid #eee6b5;
}
ul.insideAccor > li{
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

table#docListTable > tbody > tr > td a:visited{
text-decoration:none !important;
color:#800080;
}
ul.insideAccorList > li{
 padding: 5px 0 5px 60px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 border-top:1px solid #eee6b5;
}
/*style links inside accordion list*/
ul.insideAccorList li a:link{
color:#0000ff !important;
text-decoration:underline !important;
}
ul.insideAccorList li a:hover{
color:#0000ff !important;
text-decoration:underline !important;
}
ul.insideAccorList  li a:visited{
text-decoration:underline !important;
color:#800080 !important;
}
ul.indentList > li{
 padding-left:20px;
}
.noPadTop{
 padding-top: 0 !important;
}
li.nestedElemAccor{
 margin-top: -20px;
}


h2.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default { /*add arrowhead*/
font-size:1.2em;
background-image: url("/site-resources/resource-files/img/arrow-lg.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:0% 50%;
width:100%;
}
h2.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active {  /*add arrowhead*/
font-size:1.2em;
background-image: url("/site-resources/resource-files/img/arrow-lg-dn.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:0% 50%;
width:100%;
}
h3.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default {  /*add arrowhead*/
font-size:1.2em;
padding-left:15px;
background-image: url("/site-resources/resource-files/img/arrow-sm.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:5px 3px;
width:95%;
}
h3.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active {  /*add arrowhead*/
font-size:1.2em;
padding-left:15px;
background-image: url("/site-resources/resource-files/img/arrow-sm-dn.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:5px 3px;
width:95%;
}
li.NestElemTitle{
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
text-align:left;
}
.singleColumn h2{
font-size:1.2em;
margin-left:5px;
}
.singleColumn h3{
font-size:1.2em;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class = "docsAccordion">
<li>
 <h2><a href="#">(February 19, 2013 - May 12)</a></h2>
 
 </li>
 <li>
 <h2><a href="#">(February 19, 2012 - May 11)</a></h2>
  
</li>
 <!-- element which hold Individual class in accordian -->
<li>
 <h2><a href="#">September 10, 2007</a></h2>
  
 <li>
 <h2><a href="#">(February 19, 2011 - May 10)</a></h2>
  <ul class="docsAccordion nestedElemAccor"> 
    <li class = "nestedElems"> 
    <h3><a href="#">December 2001 (4 Meeting days)</a></h3>
     <ul class="insideAccor">
      <li>
      <p>gsdrfg</p>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "nestedElems">
     <h3><a href="#">February 2002 (7 Meeting days)</a></h3> 
     
    </li>
   <li class="nestedElems">
    <h3><a href="#">November 2001 (6 meetings days)</a></h3>
     <ul class="insideAccor">
      <li>
      <ul class="insideAccorList">
       <li><a href="http://www.google.ca">Monday February 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.bing.ca">Tuesday February 4</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.ca">Wednesday Februaary 5</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.apple.ca">Thursday February 6</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.sony.ca">Tuesday February 11</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
 </li>
<!-- END element which hold Individual class in accordian -->
 <li>
 <h2><a href="#">(February 19, 2010 - May 09)</a></h2>
  
 </li>
 <li>
 <h2><a href="#"> (February 19, 2009 - May 08)</a></h2>
  
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Created the following JSFiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lf91v2zu/ - I was unable to replicate the issue or maybe I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hi, the problem is in IE7, unffortunately we have some legacy apps that use ie7. JSfiddle doesn't seem to work in IE7 emulator in dev tools. I'm not sure how it can be tested? thanks